# Why does this ocaml snippet cause a stackoverflow?

Tags: ocaml

When I execute `table2` with an `expr` which does not consist solely of `Var`, `eval2` causes a stackoverflow. Why does this happen?

```
type bool_expr =
    | Var of string
    | Not of bool_expr
    | And of bool_expr * bool_expr
    | Or of bool_expr * bool_expr

let table2 a b expr =
    let rec eval2 av bv xpr = match expr with
        | Var(str) -> if str = a then av 
                      else if str = b then bv
                      else failwith "expression contains invalid var"
        | Not(xpr) -> (not (eval2 av bv xpr))
        | And(xpr1, xpr2) -> ((eval2 av bv xpr1) && (eval2 av bv xpr2))
        | Or(xpr1, xpr2) -> ((eval2 av bv xpr1) || (eval2 av bv xpr2)) 
    in
    [(true, true, eval2 true true expr)];;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable all warnings (or at least warning 27) then the issue should be obvious.

Comment: **Innocuous unused variable: unused variable that is not bound with let nor as, and doesn’t start with an underscore (_) character** is the warning you were talking about. But I still cannot see where this should be an issue ^^'

Comment: If you want to enable the warning locally, you can do it with `let[@warning "+27] table = ...` .

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to explain the error anyway, despite its obviousness. Answers on Stack Overflow are required to be self-contained and provide a *direct* answer to the question being asked, not an indirect one. Furthermore, a description of the error makes this more searchable.